# How to create a component library for remix run

Tags: material-ui, server-side-rendering, rollup, remix.run

I am trying to build a custom react component library to use within a remix app.
and using rollup for bundling,

everything seems to work fine up until I've added MUI5 to my custom lib,
 Now every time I try to use a MUI component I get error `Error: Invalid hook call.`

Didn't find a solution anywhere...
I tried:

- Playing with moving mui to peerDependencies,
- Using rollup `rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external`

any ideas?

Comment: Please include a sample of your code where you're importing/using an MUI component and getting the error.

Comment: Have you managed so fix it?

Comment: I ended up using nx